# Detect string pattern in database

Tags: python, pandas

I trying to find the same pattern in the variable "Municipio" in another variable named "Municipio Estabelecimento". That is the dataframe:

```
data = {'id': [1,2,3],
        'Municipio_Estabelecimento':["['SAO PAULO'],['BRUSQUE']", "['SAO PAULO']", "['SAO PAULO'], ['CAMPINAS'], ['PORTO ALEGRE']"  ],
        'Municipio': ["['SAO PAULO']", "['SAO PAULO']", "['ARIQUEMES']"]}

dataset = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(dataset.head())
```

When I used the regex pattern inside the function works:

```
dataset['Municipio_Estabelecimento'].str.contains('BRUSQUE')
```

However, when I tried to use the data frame variable inside the function, did not work!

```
dataset['Municipio_Estabelecimento'].str.contains(str(dataset['Municipio']))
```

Comment: did you mean `str(data['Municipio'])` instead of `str(dataset['Municipio'])`?

Comment: Try:  `dataset.apply(lambda x: x['Municipio'] in x['Municipio_Estabelecimento'], axis=1)`  You need to check line by line if Municipio is in Municipio_Estabelecimento.

Comment: Work perfectly!! tks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that column `Municipio` contains a list with single value then you can use

```
dataset[dataset.apply(
    lambda x: x['Municipio'][0] in x['Municipio_Estabelecimento'], axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
    id  Municipio_Estabelecimento                        Municipio
0   1   ['SAO PAULO'],['BRUSQUE']                        ['SAO PAULO']
1   2   ['SAO PAULO']                                    ['SAO PAULO']
2   3   ['SAO PAULO'], ['CAMPINAS'], ['PORTO ALEGRE']    ['ARIQUEMES']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set and then create a list of all the words that are in both lists

```
print(list(set(data['Municipio']) & set(data['Municipio_Estabelecimento'])))
```